# Laminas toRoute as POST?

Tags: php, http, post, laminas

I work with Laminas and in a ControllerAction function I want to redirect to another url as a post by using `$this->redirect()->toRoute('newSite', $noURLParams, $options);`
When I use the "query"-Option (`$options = [$query => ['postPara1' => 'blabla', 'postPara2' => 'blubblub']]`), I will get the "post"-Parameter as GET-Parameter in the URL:

hhttp://localhost/new-site?postPara1=blabla&postPara2=blubblub

So everyone could see the content of the parameters.

Is there a way to get the toRoute() to make a "POST" out of it?
Or do I have to use another function for this?

Comment: Sounds a bit weird. Why don't you send the post data directly to the route you want to redirect to? Direct http redirecting with post data is impossible as far as i know.

Comment: Because I decide in the "action" how it goes on. I do this with the help of database operations, which I cannot call in Javascript. And this toRoute-Action is already an existing module, so I don't have to implement it all over again.

Comment: Can you show us some code that illustrates your problem? Maybe an event-driven solution is better than your plan of a redirect, which will not work with POST data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your interest and help. After you said that it doesn't work, I changed the sequence of what, when should be called and now I can do it without an additional redirect.